# What's the easiest way to automate the setup of Gulp and associated plugins?

Tags: gulp

I find myself manually installing Gulp and a series of plugins for each new project of mine. Is there a strightforward way to automate that, without having to learn a whole bunch of stuff?

Comment: `npm install gulp --save-dev`?

Comment: Yes that's the first thing I do, followed by about ten "npm install..." lines for installing all the plugins I use in my gulpfile.js. I'm looking for a way to automate all of this

Comment: Just a regular `npm install` should install all of the Node package dependencies based on your `package.json`. Then a regular `gulp` should install all of the Gulp dependencies based on your `gulpfile.js`. Outside of running those two commands, I'm not sure how you can really 'automate' it for local development (you can easily add it to a build process). Setting up automation for a ~5 second one-off task for local development would seem a bit counter-productive.

Comment: But package.json is created by npm install. So for each new project it's always fresh, how then can I use this fresh file to install automatically all the Gulp plugins I need? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `npm init` before you do the `npm install gulp --save-dev` statements. The `npm init` creates a file called `package.json` that will allow you to simply do a `npm install` when you need to start again somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand how this will allow me to NOT install manually each Gulp plugin one by one

Comment: Create a fresh folder. Navigate to that folder using command line. Type 'npm init'. That will create a file called package.json. Now type the 'npm install gulp-pluginNameHere --save-dev' for each plugin you require. As you do each one watch NPM automatically populate a line in the package.json file. Once your finished commit the package.json with the rest of your files in version control. Next time you want to check out your project on another computer simply checkout from version control and run 'npm install' from the command line in the folder you just checked out.